# Google Store Locator error while loading js assets

Tags: 7, google-maps

I've installed Google store locator set of modules on Drupal and for a while all worked fine, however now, seemingly our of the blue it stopped working. When looking at Chrome's console I can see it can't load `sites/all/libraries/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js` nor `sites/all/libraries/storelocator/js/store-locator.compiled.js` even though both files are there. I've changed the files permissions to 644 then 777 to see if it was a permission issue, but that didn't resolve the problem.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: storeLocator is not defined` and I also get a red GET while trying to load these libraries.

Comment: What's the exact error? What are request and response header?

Comment: I think you are not using clean url. http://site/?q=store_locator did not work.